# Angular ajax - Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I have the following code to create a post request from angular 6 to my webservice.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const headeroptions = { headers: headers };
return this.http.post(this.config.productsUrl + '?' + this.common.queryBuilder(options), {data: 'test'}, headeroptions);
```

It shows results in browser network pannel,but shows error in console like

> Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the your hostname in allowed CORS of the api.

Comment: i am just tying from ng serve --open

Comment: I am talking about this microservice this.config.productsUrl

Comment: If you just doing it for testing purpose, then to bypass this error on your browser install CORS chrome extension